# Get Symfony URL relative to the index file

Tags: symfony1

I have a symfony project which, because of DNS issues, is `http://<project-name>/` locally, but it needs to be `http://<qa-host-name>/<project-name>;/` when hosted in a more QA level environment but it may be `http://<domain-name>/` for production (so, I need this to work for both). Now, the images folder will always be relative to the `<project-name>` directory, so locally it will be `http://<project-name>/my-smilie.png` and on QA it will be `http://<qa-host-name>/<project-name>/my-smilie.png`

Since everything is relative to the URL of the index.php, I thought that Symfony would have something to create dynamic URLs which work even if the context is different so that my `template.php` could have something like

```
<?php echo image_url("my-smilie.png"); 
      /*see below for potential implementation*/?>
```

and it would output `http://<project-name>/my-smilie.png`, `http://<qa-host-name>/<project-name>/my-smilie.png`, or `http://<domain-name>/my-smilie.png`.  (Relative URLs are fine, but absolute would be better).

Below is an example of what I am looking for, but I feel like I am trying to re-invent the wheel and that Symfony has already accomplished this.

```
function image_url($img)
{
    return get_base_url() . '/images/' . $img;
}


function get_base_url()
{
    $par = dirname( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] );
    if($par == "/") $par = "";
    return $par;
}
```

Comment: Why not create subdomains on the QA domain for each project?

Comment: One of the stages is being sent out through dyndns, that means I can't create subdomains.

Comment: I admit, that is a terrible solution, but it solves a number of other problems.

Comment: why would absolute urls be better?  I thought this was exactly the strength of relative urls.

Comment: If the browser is being redirected through htaccess, it has no ability to determine if the relative root is host/, host/sub-folder, or host/some/crazy/structure/over/here

Comment: Relative URL is fine so long as everyone can tell what is a folder and what isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `public_path('images/smilie.jpg')` function

[public_path() manual](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_public_path)

Answer (score 3):

I just came across a situation where the `public_path` helper does not work terribly well, but there is an alternative:

```
    // this populates $host with absolue URL of the parent directory 
    // of the Symfony script
    $host = $request->isSecure()? 'http://':'https://';
    $host .= $request->getHost() . $request->getRelativeUrlRoot();
```